# Publishing new android release before pervious one approved

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have published my first release of android APP on Google Play console, Its not approved  yet (Still In Review for 5 days now).

I found that the app has an error and will crash on start.
I want to discard the first release and publish the new one which contains the fixes.

I think my app still in review for 5 days now because it crashes and I want to fix it but don't know how.

If I try to publish a new release on Google Play, it says "You cannot remove all production APKs and Android App Bundles"

Any Help

Comment: Are you trying to remove the old artifacts too? (The older APK/AAB) You don't actually need to do that, just upload a release with a higher version code. I don't know if there's a restriction if the app hasn't been approved yet, but I feel like it *shouldn't* matter - there are testing and pre-release tracks you can keep updating, and when you push to production there's just a delay while it's approved. I feel like you should be able to update, it just might reset your place in the review queue (and it does take a week or so for the first approval at the moment, it's not just you!)

Answer (score 0):

I have actually uploaded an update version of an app before its first release was approved and published. (The reason was I forgot obfuscation...) It was approved and published later without problem.

But I can't understand your saying:

> If I try to publish a new release on Google Play, it says "You cannot
> remove all production APKs and Android App Bundles"

If you tried just uploading an update version, I can't understand why it led to **remove all production**.

If you didn't just upload an update version but you tried to **remove** or something, you might doing something wrong. But you didn't disclose detail about that, nothing could suggest anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just exit upload window. Find button "сontinue uploading" in versions section and upload yours's new version of application.